# How to allocate space for a Vec<T> in Rust?

Tags: vector, rust

I want to create a `Vec<T>` and make some room for it, but I don't know how to do it, and, to my surprise, there is almost nothing in the official documentation about this basic type.

```
let mut v: Vec<i32> = Vec<i32>(SIZE); // How do I do this ?

for i in 0..SIZE {
    v[i] = i;
}
```

I know I can create an empty `Vec<T>` and fill it with `push`es, but I don't want to do that since I don't always know, when writing a value at index `i`, if a value was already inserted there yet. I don't want to write, for obvious performance reasons, something like :

```
if i >= len(v) {
    v.push(x);
} else {
    v[i] = x;
}
```

And, of course, I can't use the `vec!` syntax either.

Comment: If you're creating a new vector you *will* know if a value exists. Note that quite a few answers here assume you're creating a new vector, if this isn't the case *(from the second part of the question seems its not)* it would be good to make that more clear in the question. The answer for a new compared to an existing vector are quite different.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the first syntax of [the `vec!` macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.vec.html), specifically `vec![elem; count]`. For example:

```
vec![1; 10]
```

will create a `Vec<_>` containing 10 `1`s (the type `_` will be determined later or default to `i32`). The `elem` given to the macro must implement `Clone`. The `count` can be a variable, too.

Comment: Thank you. Well, it was in the documentation. I couldn't find it when I searched for it, though.

Comment: This no longer works, that method appears to have been removed.

Comment: @Rory Runs with 1.0 now

Comment: This is easier to remember than ::with_capacity();
.. vec![0; 10]; it works in latest Rust 1.4.4

Answer (score 58):

While `vec![elem; count]` from the accepted answer is sufficient to create a vector with all elements equal to the same value, there are other convenience functions.

[`Vec::with_capacity()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.with_capacity) creates a vector with the given capacity but with zero length. It means that until this capacity is reached, `push()` calls won't reallocate the vector, making `push()` essentially free:

```
fn main() {
    let mut v = Vec::with_capacity(10);
    for i in 0..10 {
        v.push(i);
    }
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

You can also easily [`collect()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) a vector from an iterator. Example:

```
fn main() {
    let v: Vec<_> = (1..10).collect();
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

And finally, sometimes your vector contains values of primitive type and is supposed to be used as a buffer (e.g. in network communication). In this case you can use `Vec::with_capacity()` + [`set_len()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.set_len) unsafe method:

```
fn main() {
    let mut v = Vec::with_capacity(10);
    unsafe { v.set_len(10); }
    for i in 0..10 {
        v[i] = i;
    }
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

Note that you have to be extra careful if your vector contains values with destructors or references - it's easy to get a destructor run over a uninitialized piece of memory or to get an invalid reference this way. It will also work right if you only use initialized part of the vector (you have to track it yourself now). To read about all the possible dangers of uninitialized memory, you can read the documentation of [`mem::uninitialized()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.uninitialized.html).

Comment: `set_len` *can* work correctly with non-`Copy` types: you just have to be careful. And it can be broken with `Copy` types, e.g. `&int` is `Copy` but it's highly likely that the random uninitialised memory will not be a valid `&int`. (It's very dangerous!)

Comment: @dbaupp, yeah, I probably did not formulate it right. Thanks!

Comment: Probably better to iterate over the vector with enum, so every assignment doesn't need to be bounds checked. (possibly bounds checks will be optimized out - but it depends on the complexity of the loop)

Answer (score 3):

There is the [`Vec::resize`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.resize) method:

```
fn resize(&mut self, new_len: usize, value: T)
```

This code resizes an empty vector to 1024 elements by filling with the value `7`:

```
let mut vec: Vec<i32> = Vec::new();
vec.resize(1024, 7);
```

Comment: While worth noting, this only works if you're assigning the same value - the OP assigns increasing indices.